Adding static text to word doc from LWC generation
I am exploring generating a word doc from an LWC that results in SF data via this blog post https://codingwiththeforce.com/salesforce-development-tutorial(lwc):-how-to-generate-a-word-document-from-a-lightning-web-component/
The one thing it doesn't show in here is how to make the word doc look like an actual document where there is both static text and SF returned data (like a SF email template) Using the method in this blog post, I can get the data to return from the apex query but not sure how to append static text by these returned SF data values.
does anyone have experience in how to do this? thanks!

Looking at the provided code, you should pass your static text to the generateTextRun method:
e.g. static text
this.generateTextRun("This is my static text")

e.g. mixed static and dynamic text
this.generateTextRun("Last Name: " + contactPassed["LastName"].toString())

This will put the text in the generated table cells. To put text in e.g. a paragraph, you will have to use the right command from the docx library: https://docx.js.org/#/usage/paragraph
(I recommend going through the library docs, they're pretty good)

this helps thank you!!  one very minor thing i'm running into- i'm having trouble getting a space in between values (i'm putting the mixed static and dynamic text in the generateRow method for each row. I tried a + ""  at the end but no space appears. do you know what is best to use? thanks!

Can you give an example of the value you're providing and the value it's outputting, because I don't understand what space you're talking about unfortunately.
